# Error regarding a simple C program involving scanf()

Tags: c, scanf

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    double NET_Income = 9999.58;
    printf("Enter your NET monthly income: ");
    scanf("%f", &NET_Income);

    while (NET_Income < 500.00) OR (NET_Income > 400000.00); {
        printf("Sorry, that is an incorrect amount, please re-enter your NET monthly income: ");
        scanf("%f", &NET_Income);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

When I try to run this code in visual studio I get the following errors:

Return value ignored: 'scanf'

Warning C4477   'scanf' : format string '%f' requires an argument of type 'float *', but variadic argument 1 has type 'double *'

Warning C4013   'OR' undefined; assuming extern returning int

```
'scanf' : format string '%f' requires an argument of type 'float *', but variadic argument 1 has type 'double *
```

Comment: There's no `OR` operator in C, it's `||`.

Comment: The format operator for `double` is `%lf`, not `%f`.

Comment: Use `%lf` instead

Comment: There is `or` per `<iso646.h>` ...

Comment: It's C, not Python.

Comment: You cannot use any input function correctly unless you ***check the return*** to validate the input succeeded -- otherwise you invite undefined behavior in your code by failing to detect an input failure.

Answer (score 2):

There are quite a few problems with this code:

- as noted in the comments, the `scanf` format specifier for a `double` is `%lf`, not `%f`
- the return value from `scanf` indicates whether the function succeeded or not, and should be checked ([documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf))
- `while (NET_Income < 500.00) OR (NET_Income > 400000.00); {` contains several errors, including use of `OR` (which doesn't exist) and some unwanted extra brackets.  Also, you don't want that semi-colon in there, although perhaps that's just a typo.  Anyway, it should be: `while (NET_Income < 500.00 || NET_Income > 400000.00) {`

---

There have been some points raised in the comments about the return value of `scanf`, so I thought I would clarify.  cppreference defines it as:

> Number of receiving arguments successfully assigned (which may be zero in case a matching failure occurred before the first receiving argument was assigned), or EOF if input failure occurs before the first receiving argument was assigned.

Where 'input failure', means that input characters were unavailable, and 'matching failure', means that the input was inappropriate (e.g., in this case, not numeric).

So, in this case, since we are only scanning for a single argument at a time, a return value of `1` means success', and anything else means failure.  You might attempt some kind of recovery strategy if `scanf` fails, but that is beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: `scanf` returns the number of inputs that were successfully scanned. In this case it should return 1 on success. It might not return an error. It could return 0 if somehow it scanned the input and didn't find any values. It could return EOF. It's not the typical ANSI success or error function.

Comment: @bruceg Sure.  I class returning `1` as 'success', in the code as posted.

Comment: Re “the return value from scanf indicates whether the function succeeded or not”: The return value from `scanf` indicates how many input items were assigned or that an error occurred before the first conversion. Return values of less than the full number of items are not necessarily a failure, as `scanf` can be used to make a decision about how to parse further, not to decide that input has failed, and a return value of the full number of items does not indicate all matches were successful, as there may be unmatched literals or conversion specifiers with suppressed assignments.